# ServiceStack...'Memory is corrupt'

Tags: iis, servicestack

I have an application pool that Utilizes Service Stack. This application pool is getting recycled on its own due to some Errors. I am not very good at dumps and such, but the following is what I have gotten to at this point by capturing a dump on the worker when it gets recycled:

```
memory is corrupt
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask.InnerInvoke() 
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() Line 2523    
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecutionContextCallback(object obj) Line 2888
```

The issue is occurring on Windows 2008 Servers. I have no evidence that on newer versions it will rectify this. What I can say is that in some environments it happens much less frequently, and in some, quite a lot more often.

Not sure what code I can show that will be helpful, and ideas is greatly appreciated.

My app pool recycles, and my users are all logged out.

Comment: Unless you can provide a [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can identify the cause it's very unlikely anyone will be able to help, but to mitigate the side-effects you can use a [Distributed Caching Provider](https://docs.servicestack.net/caching) or a Stateless Auth Provider like [JWT](https://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider) which will preserve User Sessions across App Pool recycles.

Comment: According to you error codes, it seems that you have provided a error message not a dump related information. If you want to analysis the dump, I suggest you could try to use prodump or other tool to capture the native crash dump and then you could try to use debugdiag analysis to analysis it.  Details ,you could refer to this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/919792/how-to-use-the-debug-diagnostics-tool-to-troubleshoot-a-process-that-h).